How to remove additional spaces from sentence and to have no spaces before a dot or comma
Currently looking for a way to remove additional spaces for example in a sentence like:
"Good morning  , I have   just taken a walk outside ." and have it instead be
"Good morning, I have just taken a walk outside."
In Typescript. Currently had something like this with regex:
private trimText(text: string): string {
    return text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
}

But this would make it as such "Good morning , I have just taken a walk outside ." with the additional spaces before the comma and dot. What would be a good way to approach this which makes it also understandable for others which read the code?

How about text.replace(/\s+,/g, ',').replace(/\s+\./g, '.').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()

So "Make sure to delete your .git directory" should turn into "Make sure to delete your.git directory" ?

Also, what about other punctuation like "Are you there ?"

"A good way" is still fairly subjective. By what metric will you judge whether a way is "good" or not? As I mentioned above, there are lots of ways to do this. There's lookahead as shown here, or replacement with the final character instead of with a space as shown here.  Or the callback as shown in the answer below, etc. What's your criterion for success?

You can use a replace callback and return a proper replacement based on the punctuation sign presence:


const input = ' Good morning , I have    just taken a walk outside .'

console.log(input.replace(/\s+[.,]?/g, m => m.endsWith('.') || m.endsWith(',') ? m.slice(-1) : ' ').trim());



